# Activity Tokens in SMS via Civi Rules

Tags: tokens, civirules, activity, sms

I'm trying to set up sms reminders for activities. And am trying to configure this with CiviRules.

For example, a client has an initial assessment with our youth service. I want to send a reminder email the day before

But when I set this up using scheduled reminders, the message includes both activity tokens and contact tokens from the message template.

When I set up the same message using rules, only the contact tokens are filled.

I'm trying to avoid using scheduled reminders because I have several "services" that use Civi, so an initial assessment reminder for our youth team, will need to be different from the message sent in our advice service reminder. (service is a custom activity field).

And I can only set scheduled reminders at the activity level, not filter by custom values.

Is there anyway that an SMS sent via Civi Rules can pick up the related activity details?

Is there another way to manage this?

At a push I could create multiple activity types

- service a assessment
- service b assessment
- service c assessment

But I'd rather not, our "actions" list on the contact record is already longer than my arm
And potentially I want to roll the sms reminders out across other activity types in future- which will only compound this problem